# A question on part of "An introduction to teichmuller spaces" by Imayoshi-Taniguchi

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I was reading the part on Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates, the proof on page 64, I don't understand when they say:

> Since 
>   $\theta_j(t_1)=\theta_j(t_2)$, $j=1,\ldots,3g-3$, all $g_k$ can be glued together into marking-preserving homeomorphism, say $h$ of $R_{t_1}$ onto $R_{t_2}$. Since $h$ is holomorphic on $R_{t_1}$ except for a finite number of analytic curves, so is $h$ on the entire $R_{t_1}$ by Painleve's theorem...

My questions are:

- how do different twisting parameters determine different points in the Teichmüller space?
- I would like to know some reference for this Painleve's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference for Painleve's theorem:

http://eom.springer.de/p/p071100.htm (the second paragraph).

I don't understand your first question.

Comment: My first question is related to this part:

$\theta_j(t_1)=\theta_j(t_2),j=1,\ldots,3g-3$ all $g_k$ can be glued together into marking-preserving homeomorphism. 

Why?




Comment: For those of us who don't have the book in front of us, why don't you explain (preferably in the original question) what the notation means?

Comment: The link to `eom.springer.de` is broken, but the article can now be found at https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_theorem.